# Which is correct: "The animal within you" or "The animal within yourself"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns

I'm coming up with a slogan for my DJ personal brand. I want to convey the idea that we all have a wild side in us waiting to be triggered. From similar questions, it seems that either version would work in the given context, but there were no upvotes or response, so I'm not sure about validity.

Which is proper" "The animal within you" or "The animal within yourself"?

Example: "Hey friend, there is an animal within you waiting to be unleashed". From here, the slogan would be cut down to "The animal within you".

The first version using "you" would be ideal, otherwise I will come up with something completely different.

Thanks all!

Comment: What's wrong with "The animal within you"? With would mean an animal next to you, not inside of you.

Comment: I made an error, should have said "The animal within you" or "The animal within yourself". My apologizes for the confusion

Comment: Please edit the body of the question, too. There is no need here for a reflexive pronoun, but please give us a complete sentence to analyze.

Comment: Sorry again, fixed. Example: "Hey friend, there is an animal within you waiting to be unleashed". And from that, the slogan would be cut down to "The animal within you".

Comment: My vote is for "within you" Welcome to the Stack Exchange, Matthew! Don

Comment: Please edit the entire sentence into your question, so those who wish to help don't have to read through all the comments. :)

Comment: Oh boy, I'm not all that good at this! Anyway, thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! This community is clearly quite helpful and knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0):

“The animal within you” is better. “Yourself” is distracting, as if the animal could be hiding in him- or herself.

Comment: Great point! I agree with "yourself" being distracting. I want it to sound informal and conversational. How it might typically be worded in every day usage.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that "you" is said with both "within" and "in", but that "yourself" is said only with "within" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=animal+within+you%2Canimal+within+yourself%2Canimal+in+you%2C+animal+in+yourself&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canimal%20within%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimal%20in%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimal%20in%20yourself%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Canimal%20within%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimal%20in%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimal%20in%20yourself%3B%2Cc0)). From the sense that can be made out from the books the meaning is the same in all three cases. It seems to me, therefore, that you can use as well "the animal within yourself"  at no risk of being wrong. However, if you want an expression with the most chance to sound familiar to the greatest number, you should use "within you", or even "in you".

[image]

Comment: Wonderful insight! Also, I really like the idea of cutting it down even more into "animal in you". Packs more of a punch.